# Jacobian of a 1-form on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, differential-forms, vector-fields, jacobian

Let $X$ be a smooth vector field on a manifold $M$. The Jacobian of $X$ at a critical point $x^*$ is the linear map
$$X'(x^*): T_{x^*}M \rightarrow T_{x^*}M$$
where $T_{x^*}M$ is the tangent space to $M$ at $x^*$, defined by
$$X'(x^*) \cdot u = \frac{d}{dt} \left( \text{d}_{x^*}\Theta_t \cdot u \right)|_{t=0}$$
for any $u \in T_{x^*}M$.

Here $\Theta_t: M \rightarrow M$ is the flow of $X$ and $\text{d}_{x^*}$ is the differential, so $\text{d}_{x^*}\Theta_t$ is a linear map of $T_{x^*}$ to itself, since $x^*$ is a critical point:
$$\text{d}_{x^*}\Theta_t: T_{x^*}M \rightarrow T_{\Theta_t(x^*)}M = T_{x^*}M$$

Chosen a local chart at $x^*$, the matrix representation of this linear map is the usual Jacobian matrix:
$$\left[ X'(x^*) \right]_{ij} = \left( \frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^j} \right)_{x = x^*}$$

See e.g. Abraham-Marsden (1978), Foundations of mechanics, p. 72 (page attached below).

**Question**
*Is there an analogue coordinates-independent definition for the "Jacobian" of a 1-form $\alpha$ on a manifold $M$ as a linear map on a cotangent space and such that the local representative is the usual Jacobian matrix?*

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, and, in fact, it is a more general notion. The construction is often called the *intrinsic derivative*. Any time you have a smooth section $s$ of a vector bundle $E\to M$, its derivative *at a zero* $p$ is a well-defined linear map $Ds_p\colon T_pM\to E_p$.

Of course, you can work in a trivialization on an open set $U$ containing $p$ and then $s$ corresponds to a function $f_U\colon U\to\Bbb R^k$ for $V\subset\Bbb R^n$ and we can consider the derivative $(Df_U)_p\colon T_pM \to \Bbb R^k$. If you have an additional, overlapping trivialization on $V$, then on $U\cap V$ we have $f_V(x)=g_{UV}(x)f_U(x)$, where $g_{UV}\colon U\cap V\to GL(k)$ is the transition function of the vector bundle. In general, $(Df_V)_p = g_{UV}(p)(Df_U)_p + (Dg_{UV})_p f_U(p)$, but at a *zero* of the section, the second term vanishes and we see that $(Df_U)_p$ defines a well-defined mapping $T_pM\to E_p$.

Comment: I’ve never heard of this before! The main example I can think of is the Hessian of a function at critical point. But does it appear anywhere else?

Comment: @Deane Just as one computes the index of a vector field at a zero, one can compute this for a section of any oriented vector bundle and then compute the Euler class. I recall encountering it in singularity theory, as well

Comment: This is super interesting, thanks @TedShifrin! Any reference on it? How is ${Ds}_{p}$ actually defined? (There's a typo, the section $s$ of a vector bundle is $M \to E$).

Comment: There isn’t a typo.  $E\to M$ is the vector bundle. I actually learned this in graduate school eons ago and do not know a reference, but I told you how it’s defined :)

Comment: P.S. If you prefer, write $T_{(p,0)}E = T_pM\oplus E_p$, and project $Ds(p)$ onto $E_p$. (Only along the zer section do we have a canonical such splitting.)

Comment: Oh right sorry, I misinterpreted the sentence. Thanks, I'll work the details out :)